# Two way binding in custom directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement two way binding for custom directive in angularJs. Somehow its not working.

html file

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>Outside directive
  <input type='text' ng-model='outAttr'>{{outAttr}}</br>
  <div my-directive some-attr='outAttr'></div>
</div>
```

js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A,
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        inAttr: '=someAttr';
      },
      template: "<div><input type='text' ng-model='inAttr'>\
                {{inAttr}}</div>"
     }
})
```

Somehow its not working. here is [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/chandan_jhun/1vx1jnx2/3/). Can someone help me pointing out my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few syntax errors. The logic of your code is OK - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vx1jnx2/4/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // missing '
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            inAttr: '=someAttr' // no ;
        },
        template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="inAttr">{{inAttr}}</div>' // no break
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the ';' was the main issue there. While adding deleting I inadvertantly removed " ' " from restrict. My bad!
Just now I got it working on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandan_jhun/2naL4bam/7/)